# App crashed , deployment Heroku error in Django

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm deploying my first Django app on Heroku and i get this error:

```
2019-06-17T22:02:04.615398+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=carlosdelgado1.herokuapp.com request_id=210a779e-59ba-46c3-af78-e60215244798 fwd="24.55.161.197" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-06-17T22:34:14.393752+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=carlosdelgado1.herokuapp.com request_id=cc7678e9-c3ec-4b97-9a34-383b6f6f0a4e fwd="24.55.161.197" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

this is whats in my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn porfolio.wsgi
```

i did these import in the wsgi.py file:

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "kloudless.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

here is the github link to the blog project:
https://github.com/Poucarlos/portfolio

I'm trying to display my blog in Heroku to see it when I access it

Answer (score 1):

There should be an error before the status code. Can you include the whole Build from the start to where you get the 503 error? It might be any of the django errors like template error or modulenotfounderror. Can be fixed by identifying the error.

Comment: what do you mean the whole Build, you mean the whole code from the snippet above ,sorry for responding late